# How can I get the minimum and maximum fundamental frequency from the wave file using seewave library in R

Tags: r, audio, signal-processing, frequency, analysis

How can I get the minimum and maximum fundamental frequency from the wave file using `seewave` library in R?

I am using `autoc` command to get fundamental frequency but not able to identify the minimum/maximum and peak frequency values.

If anyone can help me to get this correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing auto-correlation on the entire audio file, or windowing?

From the documentation autoc will only return the most likely fundamental frequency, which is the ~largest autocorrelation coefficent. If you want to find the highest/lowest frequency in an audio file I would segment the audio file into short windows, perform autoc on each and then find the min/max from those.

If you infact want to find the highest/lowest peak in the autocorrelation coefficents you may want to roll your own (or I think R has something called acf()). [This](http://www.katjaas.nl/helmholtz/helmholtz.html) site is great for explaining the process of implementing your own.

Comment: Thank for your kind reply. I'm very new to this subject. We wish to perform windowing. 
Actually, I'm working on animal sounds in which I would like to find out basic acoustic features such as fundamental fq, mean, maximum, minimum etc. Here, I'm unable to figure out, how can I do this using package "seewave" in R or any other software for that matter. Any help/leads will be much appreciated. Thank you.